# Joins and subqueries in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[image]

I am trying to find all continents and their most-used currency.

- ContinentCode
- CurrencyCode
- CurrencyUsage

I am not familiar with grouping so I will be very grateful if you can give me a hint using only subqueries and joins if they can be used adequately here.

[image]

[image]

Comment: How do you define “most used currency”?

Comment: The currency that is used in most countries.

Comment: @RBarryYoung, added a third picture that shows the data in the Countries table.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on grouping: https://www.dofactory.com/sql/group-by

Comment: For this sort of question you need to do your own research using any of the excellent tutorial sites and official documentation sites available and then post a question when you are stuck on a specific aspect of the problem. And as already said, please don't use images.

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

Join the countries to the continents. Then aggregate to get the number the currencies are used. Then use `row_number()` (or `rank()`, if you want to keep ties) to produce an ordinal per continent -- the more the currency is used the lesser the ordinal. Only get the rows where this ordinal equals `1`.

```
SELECT x.continentcode,
       x.currencycode,
       x.currencyusage
       FROM (SELECT ct.continentcode,
                    cy.currencycode,
                    count(cy.currencycode) currencyusage,
                    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ct.continentcode
                                       ORDER BY count(cy.currencycode) DESC) rn
                    FROM continents ct
                         LEFT JOIN countries cy
                                   ON cy.continentcode = ct.continentcode
                    GROUP BY ct.continentcode,
                             cy.currencycode) x
       WHERE x.rn = 1;
```

And next time do **not** post images of tables. Instead paste the `CREATE` and `INSERT` statements to create them as **text**.